# How to get spark streaming to continue where spark batch left off

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have monthly directories of parquet files (~10TB each directory). Files are being atomically written to this directory every minute or so. When we get to a new month, a new directory is created and data is written there. Once data is written, it cannot be moved.

I easily run batch queries on this data using spark (batch mode). I can also easily run spark streaming queries.

I am wondering how I can reconcile the two modes: batch and stream.

For example: Lets say I run a batch query on the data. I get the results of the query and do something with them. I can then `checkpoint` this dataframe. Now let's say I want to start a streaming job to only process new files relative to what was processed in the batch job, ie. only files not processed in the batch job should now be processed.

Is this possible with spark streaming? If start a spark streaming job and use the same `checkpoint` that the batch job used, will it proceed as I want it to?

Or, with the batch job, do I need to keep track of what files were processed and then somehow pass this to spark streaming so it can know to not process these.

This seems like a pretty common problem, so I am asking here to see what some other big data software developers have done.

---

I apologize for not having any code to post in this question, but I hope that my explanation is all it takes for someone to see a potential solution. If needed, I can come up with some snippets